# Use of <img src> in js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, jquery-ui

I have the following in place:

```
    var diff = maxval - ui.value;
    $( "#output").html( diff?"diff. of " + diff : "no diff" );
```

Now I'd like to add an image to each, if there's a difference in value or not, ie:

```
    var diff = maxval - ui.value;
    $( "#output").html( diff?"<img src='yes.png' height='50' width='50' /> diff. of " + diff : "<img src='no.png' height='50' width='50' /> no diff" );
```

Seeing as though that doesn't work, how can I set an image for each in that output div?

Comment: What kind of element is "output"? A single div?

Comment: What do you mean with 'doesn't work'?

Comment: 11684, As in, the images don't show in the single output div @Filippos Karapetis

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're checking based on `diff`, don't you mean to check if it's greater than 0?

Negative numbers evaluate to `true`.

```
Boolean(-1);//true
Boolean(50);//true
Boolean(-500);//true
Boolean(-0.001);//true
Boolean(0);//false
```

Here is how I'd create a new image with a source attribute decided based on diff being greater than 0.
Note, I'm using actual elements, so I'm changing the `src` attribute instead of a string value which I believe creates more readable code.

```
var diff = maxval - ui.value;
var img = new Image();
img.src = (diff > 0 ) ? "yes.png" : "no.png";
img.width = "50px";
img.height = "50px";
$( "#output").empty().append(img);
```

Here is a fully vanilla solution, including the text node:

```
var diff = maxval - ui.value;
var img = new Image();
img.src = (diff > 0 ) ? "yes.png" : "no.png"; // assuming you mean to check positive value
img.width = "50px";
img.height = "50px";
var el = document.getElementById("output");
el.appendChild(img);
var text = (diff > 0) ? "diff" : "no diff";
var txt = document.createTextNode(text);
el.appendChild(txt);
```

While the advantages of this 'longer' code don't seem obvious at first, it is very easy to manipulate. I'm working with DOM elements directly instead of strings, I can easily add or remove attributes, change properties, clone them, etc.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin. What about displaying the img and then the text in the output div?

Comment: @Dave That's what `appendChild` does in the native DOM version, and `append` does in the jQuery version. It appends an _element_ to the output div (That is, a div with an ID value of output).

Comment: Correct, trying to check positive values. Can you provide an example please with the img and `diff. of " + diff` text and the other?

Comment: Never mind :) just saw the updated answer, sorry! thank you!!

Comment: @Dave you're very welcome, being effective with JavaScript without having to rely on jQuery makes you a better developer :)

Comment: Haha thanks. Lastly, with `var text = (diff > 0) ? "diff" : "no diff";`, what if I need "diff" to display the actual difference? Can I just use `var text = (diff > 0) ? "diff of" + diff : "no diff";`?

Comment: Yes, you can. If it becomes confusing, you can convert it to a regular `if... else`. Here are some examples https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: Ok it's not working, thought it was :( on sliding it keeps adding the output (append) line after line on slider movement, and no images displayed :( can you please provide a jsfiddle? Thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30777/discussion-between-dave-and-benjamin-gruenbaum)

Comment: @Dave I tried talking to you at chat but you did not answer. I feel that my answer provides a good solution to your question.

Comment: Thank you! Just noticed this now, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand correctly the question, if so, at least this could guide you a little bit:

```
var yes = $( "<img>").attr( {"src": 'yes.png', "height": '50', "width": '50' });
var no = $( "<img>").attr( {"src": 'no.png', "height": '50', "width": '50' });

if(diff){
    $( "#output").append(yes).append('diff. of ' + diff);
}
else{
    $( "#output").append(no).append('no diff');
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/WKg3A/

Comment: You understood correctlt, thank you. However, on sliding it keeps adding the output (append) line after line on slider movement, and no images displayed :( same issue as benjamin's code above - can you please provide a jsfiddle? Thanks

Comment: Of course, take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/WKg3A/ Justo toggle the value of `diff` to `true` or `false` to see different images